# Authentication failed due to: Missing custom request token cookie

Tags: javascript, cors, azure-active-directory, backend, hapi.js

We are running a `hapi JS` server which uses `@hapi/bell` with azure provider strategy to authenticate users on the back-end

Basically, say we have our back-end running on `port225.5874.com` and there is a login route `https://port225.5874.com/api/v2/user/sso`. Here are our routes server settings.

```
routes: {
            security: true,
            cors: {
                origin: [
                    `${configConst.client.host}:${configConst.client.hostport}`
                ],
                headers: ['Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'Accept', 'Authorization', 'Content-Type', 'If-None-Match', 'Accept-language'],
                additionalHeaders: ['Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, x-ms-request-id , Authorization'],
                credentials: true
            }
        }
```

Navigating to that route directly in the browser returns us information from the azure provider. However, if we try to go to that back-end route from a front-end client (i.e. localhost) we are being thrown the following CORS error

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/... (redirected from 'https://port225.5874.com/api/v2/user/sso') from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

To us this sounds like (we might be wrong) Access-Control-Allow-Origin is missing from 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/... but we obviously don't have control over it.

Seems like we are missing something on the front-end but unsure what it would be. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The front-end should be using e.g. MSAL.js to authenticate the user and use JWT authentication in the back-end.

Or you have to somehow tell the front-end request not to follow redirects and detect the situation.

Comment: We had the front-end using MSAL.js to obtain a Bearer token. We were then passing this token to a back-end route but how does this route confirm that the passed token is authentic?

Comment: By validating the digital signs ture using public keys downloaded from the well-known endpoint. And then checking expiry times etc

Comment: There are libraries for that

Comment: Cheers for that, we've been unsuccessfully trying to validate the MSAL token passed to the back-end using `@hapi/bell`. Will look into validating the digital signatures as you suggested

Comment: One last thing, how often to the public keys refresh or change? Seems like the server would need to cache them.

Comment: Yes, you should cache them. I believe the .NET Core libraries cache them for 24 hours, so refresh once per day.

Comment: They are not changed often but they do change sometimes. There are multiple keys to enable staged rotation.

Comment: In case the JWT requested token is a V2 one, this issue might be related with the accessTokenAcceptedVersion property not being set to 2 in the app registration's manifest (Azure Portal).